# Why is this not computed at compilation time? (constexpr)

Tags: c++, compilation, constexpr

I am curious why the following code is not evaluated at compilation time:

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr static unsigned long long arrayToLong(std::array<T, N> v) {
    unsigned long long result = 0;

    for (T i : v) {
        result *= 10;
        result += i;
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr int PERM_INDEX = 999999;
    std::array<int, 10> digits{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    for (int i = 0; i < PERM_INDEX; i++)
        std::next_permutation(digits.begin(), digits.end());

    return (int) arrayToLong(digits);;
}
```

Ì would expect it to just compile to something similar to `return constant`. I realize that runtime evaluation is always valid, but is there anything in the code preventing it from being evaluated at compile time?
Do you know of any compiler that actually evaluates it at compile time?

See it on https://godbolt.org/z/EHCTos

Comment: Quality of implementation issue maybe? `constexpr` does not *guarantee* compile time evaluation. It merely *allows* it. Run time evaluation is always valid.

Comment: Is `digits` a constexpr?

Comment: `digits` is computed at run run time using non-`contexpr` functions (standard algorithm, etc).   The compiler cannot treat it as `constexpr`, which would be necessary to do the calculations in `arrayToLong()` at compile time.

Comment: @Eljay Why would it need to be? It is not a contexpr because its value is not constant. But as far as I know, that does not mean that it prevents the code from evaluating at compilation time.

Comment: Did you try clang 7?

Comment: @Peter std::next_permutation is constexpr since C++20 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation

Comment: @Fabio Yes, clang 7 does not evaluate it at compilation time either. (You can quickly check using the godbolt link)

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. Why do you think it should? Might as well ask why compilers don't constant fold all the programs in the world.

Comment: @PasserBy You are right, I have edited the questions slightly, thanks.

Comment: @JoséD - that isn't the same as saying `next_permutation()` will be evaluated at compile time.   It's saying the function can be used in a constant expression, which isn't the same thing.   Even if the OPs compiler complies with C++20 (as draft) it isn't obligated to execute the loop at compile time.